# Adding variable in HTML tag in Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

```
            String id = (String) request.getParameter("pid");
            String link1 = "http://www2.comp.cityu.edu.hk:8080/servlet/HCPconversationupperframe?pid=" + id;
            String link2 = "http://www2.comp.cityu.edu.hk:8080/servlet/HCPconversationlowerframe?pid=" + id;

            out.println("<frameset rows=\"75%,25%\">");
            out.println("<frame src=\"http://www2.comp.cityu.edu.hk:8080/servlet/HCPconversationupperframe?pid=id\" scrolling=\"auto\" >");
            out.println("<frame src=link2 scrolling=\"auto\" >");
```

I want to make my link like this http://www2.comp.cityu.edu.hk:8080/servlet/HCPconversationupperframe?pid=123 and then call the frameset to call two servlet, however i can't add variable to the link inside HTML tag, how can I do that.

Comment: i got it by myself, its find now, thak everyone

Answer (score 0):

First, you can concatenate the variable in the printed tag.

But you should really use a JSP (or some other template engine) for outputting HTML. Writing HTML in a servlet makes it really hard to manage.